# GCM CCS server does not receive upstream messages after client restart

Tags: android, client, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently working on a little Android project using the Google Cloud Messaging and I am stuck with a problem regarding the upstream process. I used the offical API Guide as reference (https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) and it works just fine, but if I restart the client application my receiving server does not receive messages from the device anymore. This happens on both real device and emulator.

I logged the process and the messages seem to reach the gcm since I receive the send_event broadcast from gcm. However the gcm does not redirect them to my server so I think the problem may be related to some kind of invalidation in the registration id. As suggested in the API I store the registration-id and the current version number in a sharedpreferences file and skip the gcm registration process if valid values are already stored in that file.

Has anyone experiences similiar problems and can point me in a direction where to search for a solution?

**Edit:** I debugged a bit further and the problem precisely occurs whenever the Client-Activity is shutdown with onDestroy(). After that I have to reset the server to receive messages from the client again so I assume that the connection gets out of sync even if the related registration-id stays the same.

Comment: can i suggest you some easier way to implement push notifications ?

Comment: i am afraid that this is not an available solution. It is an college project specifically asking for the usage of the gcm =/

Comment: My  method does use gcm, but in an easier way, why don't you have a look and decide :-)                                           tutorail 1 )https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxO3t7ZN4k4           tutorial 2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GG7agbBHFU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I will gladly have a look at it =)